# How to create a matrix from a data table using awk

Tags: awk

In short I am attempting a very basic manipulation of my data, converting a data table into a matrix using awk.

I have a data table formatted like this:

```
1 A #1 
1 B #2 
1 C #3 
1 D #4 
1 E #5 
2 A #1  
2 B #2 
2 C #3 ...etc.
```

I'd like to convert this to a matrix with this format.

```
  A A
  B B
  C C
  #1 #1
  #2 #2
  #3 #3
...etc.
```

Ideally, I'd like the matrix to function like the above, but visually to look more like this (so I know which A goes with which number):

```
  1 2
  A A
  B B
  C C
  #1 #1
  #2 #2
  #3 #3
...etc.
```

I plan to make a 10x179 matrix. I'm assuming the same method of making a 10x2 matrix (as in the example above) should be the same as making a 10x179 matrix.

Comment: Sorry but your explanations are not ambiguous, could you please give a complete and clear example and your implementation attempts?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your input has values D and E but they are not in the input, what is the reasoning behind the position of the `#` counters, why are they below?

Comment: Each letter (A,B,C,) and number (#1 #2) is a variable. Each "set" (set 1, set 2) has 10 variables that repeat (A,B, and C and #1,#2,..etc.). I am trying to rearrange (create a matrix) that has the variables in column form instead of a row (which is what it currently is). With each set having it's own column.